# How to render fusionchart graph in jsp using setXMLData?

Tags: html, jsp, fusioncharts

I'm currently working on FusionChartsFree on a small internal application and I have a small html code like this.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My First chart using FusionCharts XT</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="FusionCharts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chartContainer">FusionCharts XT will load here!</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">         
      var myChart = new FusionCharts( "Line.swf", "myChartId", "400", "300");
      var strXML = "<chart caption='Critical' xAxisName='month' yAxisName='Count' yAxisMinValue ='40' showValues= '0'><set label = 'month1' value='55'/><set label = 'month2' value='55'/><set label = 'month3' value='55'/><set label = 'month4' value='55'/></chart>" ; 
      myChart.setXMLData(strXML);
       myChart.render("chartContainer");
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The above code works perfectly and renders a graph. Now, I'm trying to do the same thing using JSP as below :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Graphs</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="FusionCharts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<%
String data="<chart caption='Minor' xAxisName='month' yAxisName='Count' yAxisMinValue ='66500' showValues= '0'>"+"\n"+"<set label = 'month1' value='66560'/>"+"\n"+"<set label = 'month2' value='66560'/>"+"\n"+"<set label = 'month3' value='66647'/>"+"\n"+"<set label = 'month4' value='66631'/>"+"\n"+"</chart>";
System.out.println(data);
%>  
<div id="chartContainer1" align="left" style="margin-top: 22px; padding-top: 310px;">blocker data</div>
            <script>
            var blocker = new FusionCharts("Line.swf", "myChartId1", "400", "300");
            var strXML1="<%=data%>";
            blocker.setXMLData(strXML1);
            blocker.render("chartContainer1");
            </script>

</body>
</html>
```

The problem comes when I'm generating the "data" String dynamically, I do not get any output. Please help

Comment: What is the output for `System.out.println(data);`?

Comment: Actually I did a little mistake and when I corrected it, the graph was rendered. But the problem comes when I generate the "data" variable dynamically

Comment: So can you paste the `data` variable contents?

Comment: Yes. The above JSP code works as far as the the string "data" is not generated dynamically

Comment: In that case try generating the `data` string dynamically and print it so it will be possible to debug the situation.

Comment: Even when it is generated dynamically the data is printing perfectly on the console but the graph is not getting rendered.

Comment: Great! Can you simply paste the generated XML here for further diagnosing the issue?

Comment: Sure .. Here it is :
`<chart caption='Blocker' xAxisName='month' yAxisName='Count' yAxisMinValue ='20'  showValues= '0'><set label = 'month1' value='0'/><set label = 'month2' value='0'/><set label = 'month3' value='0'/><set label = 'month4' value='0'/><set label = 'month5' value='0'/></chart>`

The problem as @Haritha said was with \n .. When I removed it, it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the extra "\n" in your XML of JSP page. Remove "\n" and check again, it will work fine.

When you are passing data using XMLData() function, FusionCharts expects a String of XML data without any line breaks(that are explicitly included in the XML).